# Does a co-working place provide any benefit to a freelancer

Tags: work-environment, freelancing

I'm a freelance developer.
I've been working from home for 2.5 years, with a quite solid set-up: I've my regular customers and a stable economical situation.

**PROBLEMS I CAN SEE IN MY FUTURE**

- I'm very focused and specialized on an old programming language that will be obsolete in 5 or 10 years.
- I'm not building a network, despite the fact that I can understand its importance

So, today I was watching youtube videos about a co-working spaces company, and thinking that maybe I'm missing some opportunities.

**Does, according to your experience, a co-working space help creating new relations or provide any other hidden benefits? Can you share your experience and the pros and cons you've noticed?**
EU-IT if matters.

Comment: Not enough for a proper answer, but for networking you want proper networking events like conferences (though you could do it in coworking space if you really want but that's a very limited pool of people). Most common reason I see freelancers in coworking spaces is because they do not have the ability to do the work at home comfortably.

Comment: Try the [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Trying to figure out what language has planned obsolescence in 5 years or so?

Comment: Any language that is embedded in a significantly complex system will never go obsolete. (I think I just created my own software law!)  FYI my speciality (ladder logic) is a language that was invented in the 70's and is still going strong .

Comment: There's still plenty of COBOL & FORTRAN work out there

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mention problems you see in your future... but a co-working space won't help with any points you mention.

Co-working spaces are good if you don't have space at home, don't want to work at home, or if you want a place to meet with clients.

There are some networking opportunities, as these spaces are full of start-ups. You may end up getting some work, but it's no guarantee.

It's a cool environment to be in, but if you want to network, go to specific networking events.

In the co-working space I'm at, people don't socialize much because everyone is too busy working.

I think Youtube videos are probably glamourizing it a bit, like day-in-the-life videos. See what payment options are available, some places only charge you for the days you use the office, so you could do a month trial or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with flexi's answer, but I still want to provide a few solutions to your problem:

- Participate in various events to build your network. Be it hackathons, IT events, your local meetups or communities in general. They will help you much much better than working at a co-working place.
- Start something new. Be it a Youtube channel, a blog, a personal website or an community, this will help you big time to make new contacts and network.
- Address your original problem. If you say that you're language will go obsolete, start learning something new, attractive and most importantly valued on the job market. This can be done in your free time, like weekends or so on.
- Start volunteering. You're not only helping someone, discovering new things, but growing your network too!
- As flexi said, if you're dead set of trying a co-working place, do it, take a month and see it for yourself.